# Apache Spark Worker Timeout

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I've been experiencing one issue after another with Spark and I believe it has something todo with either networking or permissions or perhaps both. There is nothing in either the master or worker logs or thrown errors that would suggest an issue.

```
15/12/29 19:19:58 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
15/12/29 19:20:13 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
15/12/29 19:20:28 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
15/12/29 19:20:43 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
15/12/29 19:20:58 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/8 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20151229141057-0000/8 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 8
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20151229141057-0000/10 on worker-20151229141026-127.0.0.1-48818 (127.0.0.1:48818) with 2 cores
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20151229141057-0000/10 on hostPort 127.0.0.1:48818 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/10 is now LOADING
15/12/29 19:21:11 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/10 is now RUNNING
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/9 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20151229141057-0000/9 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20151229141057-0000/11 on worker-20151229141023-127.0.0.1-35452 (127.0.0.1:35452) with 2 cores
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20151229141057-0000/11 on hostPort 127.0.0.1:35452 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/11 is now LOADING
15/12/29 19:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151229141057-0000/11 is now RUNNING
15/12/29 19:21:13 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I'm trying to run a stand-alone setup on Ubuntu 14.04 with spark 1.52. Everything seems to be configured correctly, but the job never seems to finish and each worker timesout.

[image]

This is remote machine from the one I am executing the job on...

[image]

The code is just one of their examples. I've also tried the Pi Estimation example too and have the same issue.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val logFile = "/Users/user/spark.txt" // Should be some file on your system
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple App").setMaster("spark://46.101.xxx.xxx:7077")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
  val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
  val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
  println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I'd be extremely grateful if someone could put me in the right direction for solving this.

--edit - additional info.

```
#spark-env.sh
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="46.101.xxx.xxx"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="46.101.xxx.xxx"
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="46.101.xxx.xxx"
```

Tried Java 7 & Java 8 with Scala 2.10.6 and 2.11.latest.

Master started with ./start-master.sh
Worker started with ./start-slave.sh spark://46.101.xxx.xxx:7077

Running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. (Digital Ocean) - No firewalls. Can telnet into master and worker from remote machine. Master and worker are both on same single machine.

Tested both Spark 1.5.2 and 1.5.0. Kept versions of Java, Scala and Spark the same between client machine (requesting) and remote server (master and worker).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're application can't find workers.  When you started up the cluster, did you start up any slaves and connect them to the master?

To start your workers and connect them to the master, run the following:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port
```

Where the **spark://ip:port** is that of the master.

Comment: You can see the two workers attached to the master in the screenshot above. I simply ran the `./start-all.sh` command. Manually doing `./start-master.sh` and `./start-worker.sh` as the same effect for me.